# Objective-C delegate or self is morphing classes

Tags: objective-c, object, delegates, self

I have 2 UIViewControllers(A,B). A is set as the delegate for B and then B is presented. The protocol is set up in B's header:

```
@protocol BDelegate <NSObject>
- (IBAction)finishOrder:(id)sender;

@end
```

delegate property is declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<BDelegate> delegate;
```

A sets B.delegate = self;
Then on a button press B calls:

```
if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate finishOrder:nil];
    }
```

However, on first run lldb gives me:

```
-[UITextInteractionAssistant finishOrder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

second run:

```
-[NSInvocation delegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

third run:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary delegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

forth run:

```
-[UITextTapRecognizer finishOrder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

So... no code changed, but self changed from A to NSInvocation and __NSCFDictionary and the delegate for B (self of A) changed to UITextInteractionAssistant and UITextTapRecognizer... Never seen anything like it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Those all look like UITextStorageDelegate is having a bit of trouble internally

Comment: I've never even heard of UITextStorageDelegate lol. This is just a simple custom delegate system.

Comment: It's the internal delegate utilized by all the editable text controls in UIKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-releasing somewhere. Try turning on Zombies, and use Instruments to track down the over-release.

Comment: I'm using ARC... how would I keep this from happening?

Comment: @MatthewClark if you have an assign delegate, try using a weak one instead. It will help prevent against objects being freed too early.

Comment: Try a runtime check using -respondsToSelector: with the delegate instead of simply checking for its existence.  Then, log it's class.

Comment: @Richard I have to target iOS4.3 so can't use weak :-(

Comment: @CodaFi results:I still get -[NSInvocation delegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ... so in B's code it suddenly things it's delegate property is of NSInvocation type...

Comment: Actually, it would seem as though the calling class is an NSInvocation... Hmm

Comment: @CodaFi results on second run: -[NSCFString delegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Yes.  Your calling class is the problem.  NSLog it's class immediately before the method call.

Comment: @CodaFi expanded check to B's self first result: self class:NSInvocation
second result: self class:NSCFString
third result: self class:__NSCFDictionary

Comment: @CodaFI but if I put the same check in the viewWillAppear both are correct: 2012-06-18 16:57:48.595 Convention[4536:607] self class:BViewController
2012-06-18 16:57:48.596 Convention[4536:607] delegate class:AViewController

Comment: Ok it seems it was the fact that I had the 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; before the self.delegate call... I swear I've done that a hundred times before and it was fine... So I had to do bool gateway hack in the viewWillAppear of A to get it to work right... and someone tell me why this code that's been there for at least 10 months suddenly broke?

Comment: It was just a matter of time before your var was replaced by a new object of a different class in memory.  Luck, I guess.